# Whole Genome Sequencing and B Chromosomes

Tags: dna-sequencing, chromosome

**Do whole genome sequencing techniques detect B chromosomes if such chromosomes are present?**

My understanding is as follows:

How the DNA material in a B Chromosome is mapped depends on the reference map and not on how the material is packaged into chromosomes for the sample being sequenced.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use differences in coverage (number of reads mapping to certain regions in reference) to infer if there is a B chromosome.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis of NGS reads coverage rate can give information on B chromosome genomic content. Have a look at the article mentioned below:

---

<sub>Valente GT et al. (2014). [**Origin and evolution of B chromosomes in the cichlid fish Astatotilapia latifasciata based on integrated genomic analyses.**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24770715) Mol Biol Evol. 2014 Aug;31(8):2061-72</sub>

Comment: Can you add a little explanation on how coverage can be used to infer B chromosome genomic content. An illustrative figure from the mention reference would also do. We would greatly appreciate some explanation in addition to providing a link to the reference.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The attached figure shows the Illumina reads coverage for two 0B, two 1B and one 2B samples. Note that the figure shows a specific genomic regions with a higher reads coverage for the 1B and 2B samples compared to the 0B ones.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Could you provide sources to your data and answer? References are encouraged here.